# netbeans 6.1 - reverse engineer java source code to UML class diagrams

Tags: netbeans, uml

i was using netbeans 7.1.2 and it didn't have any UML plug in capabilities and now i have had to resort to netbeans 6.1 and i already have two classes from which i would like to create UML Class diagrams but the reverse engineering option yields no results. I cannot generate any class diagrams. Does anyone know how to utilize the UML plug in to reverse engineer source code and create class diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible anymore I think, I looked for it as well and found nothing but that was a year ago. Something might have happened since.

Check out [EIDOS_UML](http://java.net/jira/browse/EIDOS_UML), it's a community effort to recreate the UML capabilities I think, don't know the current status of it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have followed the procedure correctly to generate the class diagram:

Right Click the Project (or select the specific packages or java files you want) then select *Reverse Engineer* option in the right click menu, this will generate model based on the selection. This is a necessary step before creating diagrams.

Then browse the model and select the package (or all the classes) for which you want Class Diagram, right click and select *Create Diagram from Selected Elements...*

Select diagram type (in this case "Class Diagram"), give a name and click finish.

I have tested it in both Netbeans 6.1 and 6.5, and it works fine.
Hope this solves your problem.